# What do you call a money printing machine?

Tags: phrase-request

What do you call a money printing machine? And what do you call the method of inflating the money supply by resorting to simply printing it (my supposition is you can use the same phrase for both purposes but with different articles)?

> The government decided to raise wages ahead of the election with [the printing machine]; in a few months, hyperinflation plunged the country into a severe economic crisis.

Comment: [The government decided to raise wages ahead of the election with [the printing machine]; in a few months, hyperinflation plunged the country into a severe economic crisis.=buzzer] Correction: The government decided to raise wages ahead of the election by printing money; in a few months, hyperinflation plunged the country into a severe economic crisis. Comment: A machine cannot raise wages.

Comment: @Lambie Is there a noun phrase for that method of increasing the money supply OTHER THAN those with ing-words (I thought they were gerunds but whatever)? You know, like 'bench press' etc.

Comment: What is the matter with you? bench press is a noun, money printing is a noun, skydiving is a noun, surfing is a noun.

Comment: @Lambie I'm wondering about a noun PHRASE. Two nouns functioning as one

Comment: money printing IS a noun phrase. Money is a noun; printing is a noun. Printing [noun] is something I learned in college.  Money is something I would like more of.  You need to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase

Answer (score 2):

"by printing money". Printing money is a method for increasing the money supply.

money is printed via offset or intaglio printing machines.

[money printing](https://www.littletoncoin.com/shop/How-Paper-Money-Is-Made#:%7E:text=The%20green%20engraving%20on%20the,portions%20of%20the%20engraved%20designs.)

Comment: Still, is there a noun phrase for the method?

Comment: Let me give you an example. You have the word 'gibbet' which refers to an object. But you can put 'the' in front of it and you'll get a method. Is this possible with 'printing machine'? If not, is there some noun phrase that describes the method (no, I don't see 'money printing' as a noun phrase)?

Comment: "But you can put 'the' in front of it and you'll get a method. Is this possible with 'printing machine'?"

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Again, you are playing games. Any noun can take "the", which I really assume you know at this point. Also, you contradict yourself as the gibbet is NOT a noun phrase.

Comment: I never said it was. I just illustrated the point that 'the' can transform an object into a method

Comment: Please stop repeating stuff about what has already been said. And changing your question into something else. No, the cannot transform an object into a method, whatever that means. And gibbeting requires no the and the gibbet is not a method. It is the object from which the cage hangs.

Comment: Please visit this entry: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/gibbet

Comment: It's explicitly part of the question

Answer (score 2):

The current buzzphrase for this phenomenon is [Quantitative Easing](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/q/quantitative-easing.asp).

The term is used as a euphemism for the simple *printing money*.  An increasing number of governmental central banks are using this term.  Probably to disguise the fact that they are just simply printing money.